# What is the difference between a MessageListener and a Consumer in JMS?

Tags: java, jms, messaging

I am new to `JMS`. As far as I understood *`Consumers`* are capable of picking messages from queue/topic. So why do you need a *`MessageListener`* because *`Consumers`* will know when they have picked up messages? What is the practical use of such a *`MessageListener`*?

Edit:From the [Javadoc of MessageListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/jms/MessageListener.html):

> A MessageListener object is used to receive asynchronously delivered
>   messages.
>
> Each session must insure that it passes messages serially to the
>   listener. This means that a listener assigned to one or more consumers
>   of the same session can assume that the onMessage method is not called
>   with the next message until the session has completed the last call.

So I am confused between the usage of the terms *asynchronously* and *serially* together. How do these two terms relate in describing the feature of `MessageListener`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The difference is that MessageConsumer is used to receive messages synchronously:

```
MessageConsumer mc = s.createConsumer(queue);
Message msg = mc.receive();
```

For asynchronous delivery, we can register a MessageListener object with a message consumer:

```
mc.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: @Evgeniy
 In AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT mode(non-transactional)
If a failure occurs while executing the receive()[synchronous] method or the onMessage()[aysnc] method, the message is automatically redelivered ?     Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712399/auto-acknowledgement-modenon-transactional-receive-vs-onmessage

Answer (score 11):

from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html):

> For **synchronous** receipt, a client can request the next message from a message consumer using one of its receive methods.
>
> For **asynchronous** delivery, a client can register a **MessageListener** object with a message consumer.

Answer (score 5):

One major difference as per my knowledge not stated in others answers is that MessageConsumer can make use of `MessageSelectors` and hence has capability to consume messages that it's interested in, where as `MessageListener` will listen to all messages.

From the J2EE tutorial doc http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnceh.html

> **JMS Message Selectors**
>    If your messaging application needs to filter the messages it receives, you can use a JMS API message selector, which allows a message consumer to specify the messages it is interested in. Message selectors assign the work of filtering messages to the JMS provider rather than to the application.