# AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT mode(non-transactional) receive vs onMessage

Tags: java, jms

I have a question :
Is this correct, as I am not able to find the same anywhere in java docs ?

From here [JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2002/jw-0315-jms.html?page=3)
In AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT mode(non-transactional)
If a failure occurs while executing the receive()[synchronous] method or the onMessage()[aysnc] method, the message is automatically redelivered

Comment: I suggest you try it.  There are many JMS implementations out there and they many not behave the way you expect even if you have understood the standard.

Comment: @PeterLawrey agree with you, as JBoss does not redeliver but Active MQ redelivers. My question is : both r right or they should follow java specifications ?

Comment: @PeterLawrey and if talk of specifications(and not of implementation) then the JavaWorld statement is correct ?? 
In AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT mode(non-transactional)
If a failure occurs while executing the receive()[synchronous] method or the onMessage()[aysnc] method, the message is automatically redelivered

Comment: I believe so, I have seen implementations didn't appear to do this reliably.  For example, is it to be delivered again, and again until onMessage doesn't fail?

Answer (score 0):

I think that if we got a message in `onMessage` it means the message is successfully delivered to the user. JMS provider must make sure that no messages are lost. `onMessage` can only wait for the next successfully delivered message, it cannot know about problems between JMS provider and JMS server.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. one thing what is the diff b/w JMS provider and JMS server. As much as I know they are same and examples are JBoss server,ActiveMQ,Tibco,IBM MQ Server etc(they are the implementations from different vendors for JMS specification javax.jms.*) given by Sun

Comment: There may be some confusion how to call them. From API: JMS Provider - a messaging system that implements the JMS API, that is this is the jar which our app uses to work with MOM. From wiki: The Java Message Service (JMS) API is a Java Message Oriented Middleware (MOM)